# I deleted <error-page> tag in web.xml, BUT it still work

Tags: jsp, servlets

Testing `<error-page>` tag in web.xml (JSP), I found something strange.

After deleting `<error-page>` tag in web.xml, it seems to still work in some browser.

Initially I wrote `<error-page>` tag in web.xml.
After checking it works correctly, I deleted that tag (for testing).
And exported my web project again.

When I opened my web site in Chrome, I expected default error page appear. But my custom error page appeared. FireFox also showed my custom error page. Only IE showed nothing (blank page).

There are no `<error-page>` tag in web.xml.

What happend?
Is there other file that specifies custom error page?
What should I do?

Thank you ^^

Comment: @developerwjk I cleared visiting history of browser. Now Chrome shows blank page. But FireFox shows my custom error page.

Comment: @developerwjk Now FireFox shows blank page ^^ Thank you. But I wonder why tomcat shows blank page. Shouldn't it be default error page provided by browser or tomcat?